# really basic newbie python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, helper

any reason why this doesn't work?

```
import random



answer = random.randint(2, 4)
print(answer)

txt = input("what number")
if answer == txt:
    print("correct")
```

every time I enter the correct answer, it just comes back empty (or as an else statement if I put it)
I had this working last night although now I cannot work out why it won't, PS. i've just started to learn python this week so please go easy on me

Comment: You are comparing integer against string, e.g. `"1" == 1` is False, you have to convert input to int.

Comment: as @zamir commented,  txt = int(input("what number")) should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

you can not compare string with integer.

```
import random

answer = random.randint(2, 4)
print(answer)

txt  = int(input("what number"))
if answer == txt:
    print("correct")
```